# touchdevices (ipad, iphone) and CSS top layer with 100% width and height?

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, overlay

hey guys,
I have a div.mapFullscreenContainer

```
#mapFullscreenContainer {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This div is shown when I scroll to the bottom and click on a button. In normal browsers this works just fine. The overlay is 100% wide and 100% high and lies on top of the page.

However on touch devices there is the problem that the overlay is always out of the viewport. Imagine the button that makes the overlay visible is in the footer of a  rather long webpage. The overlay is always at the very beginning of the page so it's not immediately visible to the user. The user has to scroll back to the top to see the overlay.

Any idea how I could fix that so it behaves like on a normal browser. `bottom:0;` instead of `top:0` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS to count and apply total height of your page to this div
 http://jsfiddle.net/seler/FjeyK/

Comment: thank you, however that's not actually the solution i'm looking for. If I use body.height(); the entire page is filled with the overlay. However I only want to have the viewport with this overlay. The thing is the overlay holds a google map. If the entire page (body) is set as its height the center of the map is again out of the viewport.

Comment: @mathiregister sample please.